# How to encode a 5 digits number to a 3 characters string

Tags: php, encoding

I want to encrypt a 5 digits character e.g. `12345` to 3 characters, is this possible?

Comment: I guess you mean encode. Encrypt is with keys.

Comment: I have 5 digit random number e.g. 12345, my requirement is to encrypt it and show only 3 characters instead of 5 digits. Is it possible with php, if not then we can use custom encyption without ASCII characters

Comment: You haven't clearly described what you're looking for here. What are your precise requirements?

Comment: What are you expecting out of this encryption?

Comment: Any 24-bit number (0 to 16777215) can be represented by three 8-bit symbols, but it would have to be binary safe.

Comment: Going from 5 characters to 3 would not be encryption but rather encoding, or at best, a hash of some sort. Whatever your goal please don't think that what you are doing will be by any means secure.

Comment: Printable character?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Using a base64-like encoding you can encode any number up to 262144 in three 7-bit safe characters. You should make an attempt at this [you know, write code] and then post a question that doesn't simply look like "please write my code for me".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with [base_convert](http://php.net/base_convert).

```
echo base_convert('12345', 10, 36); // 9ix
```

and back

```
echo base_convert('9ix', 36, 10); // 12345
```

But this approach has limitation number: 46655

From comments you could get function that helps you to convert 5 digit number without limitations.

```
$alphbet_47 = implode(array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'K')));
$alphbet_10 = implode(range('0', '9'));


echo convBase('12345', $alphbet_10, $alphbet_47) . PHP_EOL; // 4kN
// KKK the biggest number of 47 base system. 10 base representation of its is more than any 5 digit number
echo convBase('KKK', $alphbet_47, $alphbet_10) . PHP_EOL; // 103822

function convBase($numberInput, $fromBaseInput, $toBaseInput)
{
    if ($fromBaseInput==$toBaseInput) return $numberInput;
    $fromBase = str_split($fromBaseInput,1);
    $toBase = str_split($toBaseInput,1);
    $number = str_split($numberInput,1);
    $fromLen=strlen($fromBaseInput);
    $toLen=strlen($toBaseInput);
    $numberLen=strlen($numberInput);
    $retval='';
    if ($toBaseInput == '0123456789')
    {
        $retval=0;
        for ($i = 1;$i <= $numberLen; $i++)
            $retval = bcadd($retval, bcmul(array_search($number[$i-1], $fromBase),bcpow($fromLen,$numberLen-$i)));
        return $retval;
    }
    if ($fromBaseInput != '0123456789')
        $base10=convBase($numberInput, $fromBaseInput, '0123456789');
    else
        $base10 = $numberInput;
    if ($base10<strlen($toBaseInput))
        return $toBase[$base10];
    while($base10 != '0')
    {
        $retval = $toBase[bcmod($base10,$toLen)].$retval;
        $base10 = bcdiv($base10,$toLen,0);
    }
    return $retval;
}
```

Comment: Hi @sectus,  thanks for your help, your solution solves my half of problem. I have one more query, now how to convert '9ig' to '12345' again, mean i need decryption also, thanks in advance again.

Comment: @sanjaykumar , just replace arguments.

Comment: @sanjaykumar , new function added.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. your solution solved my maximum problem, only issue remains is limitation i.e. 46655. you shared a function few mins before to achieve it the numb more then 46655, but deleted again, please share that also. my actual testing numb is 56764, thanks for your help sir

Comment: @sanjaykumar , it was untested function with notices. Look at new one.

Comment: Do you *have* to use KKK as example input?

Comment: @owlstead, it's the last 3 character number of 47 base system. It shows that limit of this approach is higher than 5 digit number.

Comment: @sectus  thanks for your answer sir, you solved 100% of my problem.thanks again, you saved my lotof time.

Comment: @sectus Fair enough, we'll forget about the acronym. It's a long time since those idiots had any impact on history anyway.

Comment: @sectus thanks for your answer sir, you solved 100% of my problem.thanks again

Comment: @owlstead , oh... this is better meaning of abbr: https://www.google.ru/search?q=Kareena+Kapoor+Khan&tbm=isch :^ )